# How do I find level sets for a function on R^d, in R?

Tags: r

I am looking for an efficient way to find level sets of an arbitrary function from [0,1]^d to R.
To be clear: with a level set I mean the set of points in [0,1]^d that are mapped to the same value.

In all of my applications, the level sets are connected. They are lines, planes, or some higher dimensional hyperplane, but apart from the connectedness, they do not satisfy some general criterium.

I am looking for a subset of the level set that has a high density everywhere.

When I limit my functions to 2d, I can use the function contourLines from the package grDevices, which does exactly what I am looking for:

```
test <- function(x,y){
     y-(x^2-6*x+9)
}
Mat = matrix(0,100,100)
x <- seq(-10,10,length.out = 100)
y <- seq(-10,10,length.out = 100)
for(i in (1:100)){
    for(j in (1:100)){
       Mat[i,j] = test(x[i],y[j]) 
    }
}
cont <- contourLines(x, y, Mat, levels = 0)
```

Unfortunately I have not been able to find a function that does the same trick in higher dimensions.

To give a bit more context to the problem:
I have a 'wild' function, of which I hardly know anything, but I can easily evaluate it at any point in R^d. This function divides the R^d (or [0,1]^d, to make it a bit simpler), into a positive part (level sets larger than 0), and a negative part (level sets smaller than 0). I am looking for the boundary separating the two, which is the level set for 0.

Comment: Are the level sets convex?

Comment: @JohnColeman No, not necessarily.

Comment: If the level sets are linear (which your example snippet doesn't illustrate) there must be some underlying linear structure which can be exploited. It might help if you provided more detail.

Comment: You seem to be doing some sort of multivariable optimization. Maybe some package in https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html would be relevant.

Comment: To add to me previous comment, the level set you mention is the solution set for the optimization problem `min (f(v))^2 s.t. 0 <= v <= 1`.